# How can I manage to wait on my socket connexion without blocking the program?

Tags: python, sockets, asynchronous, flask, server

I use a client-server socket connexion to transfer some data from my Python server. The problem I have at the moment is that the creation of the server socket block the programm because it can't connect to the client.

I tried to use async but I didn't succeed

```
from flask import *
import random   
import socket
import json  
app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='')
socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
socket.bind(('',55555))

async def acceptConnexion():
    while True:
        socket.listen(10)
        client, address = socket.accept()
        print("{} connected".format( address ))

@app.route('/getInfos')
def getInfos():
    global infosThymio
    return json.dumps(infosThymio)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

I don't know where I could call my acceptConnexion() and I don't know how to manage to let this method turn in background until it can do the connexion with the client.

Comment: run the `acceptConnexion` in a separate task/thread maybe.

Comment: `select` can wait on the listen socket and on other sockets, and can be given a timeout. Unsure if relevant here so only posted as a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can separate the `accept` call to a separate thread, in this way and let the main thread continue while the side thread waits on accept.

```
import socket
from threading import Thread

socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
socket.bind(('',55555))

def acceptConnexion():
    print("running in thread")
    while True:
        socket.listen(10)
        address = socket.accept()
        print("{} connected".format( address ))    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    thread = Thread(target = acceptConnexion)
    print("you can here do bla bla")
    x = 1
    print("x", x)
    print("Main thread will wait here for thread to exit")
    thread.join()
    print("thread finished...exiting")
```

Comment: Thank you really much for you input. It works like a charm !